# Recursive printing Pascal's triangle in Java

Tags: java, recursion, pascals-triangle

I need to make two recursive Java methods to calculate the binomial(n,k) and also print out n rows of Pascal's triangle. Calculating the binomials recursively is no problem, it works fine. But how would I make a recursive method for printing it out? No for/while-loops allowed.

I have no problem printing the triangle using two for-loops but I don't even know where to start doing it recursively. Any tips?

Comment: start printing simplest, understand and then make changes to increase complexity, search on google, you will get more

Comment: Yes I was thinking I first need to understand how to print out one row but I can't even do that. I've never used recursion before.

Comment: You don't need recursion to print one row.

Comment: I don't? Even if I'm not allowed to use loops?

Answer (score 0):

tip: if you have a row of integers, like

```
1 3 3 1
```

you can generate the next row by summing together two lists element-wise: one where you prepend a 0, and one where you append a 0.

0 1 3 3 1

1 3 3 1 0 +

1 4 6 4 1

so, try to use, for example an ArrayList to store a row in, and modify this ArrayList in each recursive call according to this idea.

Comment: this answer has nothing to do with recursion

Comment: That is not true, Ross Drew (-;

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can print a single row without recursion or iteration:

```
private void printRow(List<Integer> row) {
    System.out.println(row);
}
```

Apart from printing rows you need a function to construct the next row based on the current row. You could do this by passing an iterator over the current row into your recursive methodL:

```
// previous is the previous value we iterated over, initially null.
void constructRow(Integer previous, Iterator<Integer> currentRow, List<Integer> nextRow) {
    if (nextRow.isEmpty()) { 
        // each row must start with a 1
        nextRow.add(1);
        // if there are no more elements in the current row then we are done
        if (!currentRow.hasNext()) {
            return;
        }
    }
    if (currentRow.hasNext()) {
        Integer current = currentRow.next();
        // the first time previous == null, skip the row.add and recurse
        if (previous != null) {
            // add the previous and current value to get the next value
            nextRow.add(previous + current);
        }
        constructRow(current, currentRow, nextRow);
    }
    else {
        // the iteration is done, just add a 1 to the end
        nextRow.add(1);
    }
}
```

You call this as follows:

```
List<Integer> nextRow = new ArrayList<>();
constructRow(null, row.iterator(), nextRow);
```

Now you have to come up with another recursive method to call this method repeatedly and print the row each time.